# Cordova ios jquery css doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova

In a cordova project, I try to make these calls within my main class:

```
 myclass.prototype.enablePreviewLink = function () {
  var that = this;

  $('#previewLink').attr('href', '#preview');
  $('#previewLink').css('backgroundImage', 'none');
  $('#previewLink').off('click');

  $('#previewButton').show();

  $('#previewButton').on('click', function() {
    that.myApp.showTab('#preview');
  });
}
```

It doesn't work at all: button doesn't show up and the instruction is still visible.

The fact is at the app loading, I can call this function and it works perfectly.

```
myclass.prototype.disablePreviewLink = function () {
  var that = this;

  $('#previewLink').attr('href', '#');
  $('#previewLink').css('backgroundImage', 'url("img/background-stripes.png")');
  $('#previewLink').on('click', function() {
    that.myApp.alert('You must fill the form before being able to go further', 'Nope!');
  });
  $('#previewButton').hide();
}
```

I call the second one from OnDeviceReady state and the first one is triggered when a form is filled. I verified with console, the form is correctly filled and the first function is called. But it doesn't produce any expected result.

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    this.receivedEvent('deviceready'); 
    myclass.disablePreviewLink();
}
```

Comment: Where is `.enablePreviewLink` called?

Comment: From within the `myclass` class using a `var that = this` then `that.enablePreviewLink();` in a verification function.

Comment: What is expected result? Is `click` event not attached to `#previewLink` element when `.enablePreviewLink()` is called?